# Orange alert in Chrome icon in Windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

I am looking for a way to show a kind of orange Alert on the Chrome icon to notify that a notification has been received. I have seen other questions with the same content, but the solutions have not worked for me.

[show orange Windows taskbar icon orange when a Chrome Packaged app gets a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389286/show-orange-windows-taskbar-icon-orange-when-a-chrome-packaged-app-gets-a-notifi)

I have tried with

```
var appWindow = chrome.app.window.current();
appWindow.drawAttention();
```

But it doesn't work, I'm not doing something wrong

Thanks and greetings

Comment: Is this a Chrome extension? Or just a normal webpage?

Comment: Is a normal Webpage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw a user's attention back to a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753502/draw-a-users-attention-back-to-a-tab) or even better: [Make browser window blink in task Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar)

Comment: The above code only works inside extensions is my guess. Anyway, you can show a notification, but that's it. Given that it appears in a pretty big box on screen, even while the user has another application focused, that should be enough I guess?

Comment: No Ivar, I already have the notification issue, what I want is for the browser icon to somehow show me that there is a pending message, so I had thought of showing the icon with the typical orange warning background.

With the alert if you get a kind of notice on the icon when you are not on the page, but it is on the icon of the tab and not of the browser

Comment: @BlasPiris I understand, but that's simply not possible from a regular web page. Only from extensions.